# Property file with Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, angularjs, file-io

I am a newbie for AngularJs.

I want to be able to point to different servers from different environments, viz. Dev, Test and Prod Environments.

I have all the URLs and corresponding methods in a JSON file which I am able to get when placed within the server directory structure i.e. inside `my-app/resources/properties.json`.

This file is also accessible to the user via

`http://servername:[port]/resources/properties.json`

Is there any specific way to hide this file outside the server? i.e. My app would still access the file but not the user.

**EDIT 1**: I am creating a pure HTML Javascript app i.e. MyApp won't have any server side logic. I am hooking up to a REST API provided on separate servers with different URL.
example:

- Dev URL : http://dev.mycompany.com/api/json/MyApp/
- Uat URL : http://uat.mycompany.com/api/json/MyApp/
- Prod URL : http://prod.mycompany.com/api/json/MyApp/

Comment: You can get the file via php (for example) and block it from the users by creating rules in .htaccess on your server.

Comment: What is your backend / server based on? NodeJs? PHP?